# Chart drawing couple lines, when open second file via OpenFileDialog

Tags: c#, mschart, openfiledialog

I'm making app, which taking data  from file and shows it on chart. But, when I'm adding an additional file I see 3 graphs, not 2.

I am reading csv file, parse into double and adding series. It has to be 2 graphs, but I see 3.

```
    string[] tmpStrArr;
    double x;
    double y;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        chartGraphic.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.ScaleView.Zoom(-60, 15); // -15<= y <=15
        chartGraphic.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.Zoom(-60, 2); // -15 <= x <= 2
        chartGraphic.ChartAreas[0].CursorX.IsUserEnabled = true;
        chartGraphic.ChartAreas[0].CursorX.IsUserSelectionEnabled = true;
        chartGraphic.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.Zoomable = true;
        chartGraphic.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.ScaleView.Zoomable = true;
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
        string line = "";
        ofd.Title = "Open File With Data";
        ofd.Filter = "CSV File|*.csv|TXT File|*txt";
        if (ofd.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            textBox1.Text = ofd.FileName;
            MessageBox.Show(ofd.FileName);
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ofd.FileName);
            while (line != null)
            {

                //for (int i = -15; i < 2; i++)
                //{
                //}
                line = sr.ReadLine();
                if (line != null)
                {
                    tmpStrArr = line.Split(',');
                    x = Double.Parse(tmpStrArr[0]);
                    y = Double.Parse(tmpStrArr[1]);
                    chartGraphic.Series[0].Points.AddXY(x,y);


                    listBox1.Items.Add(line);
                }
            }
            chartGraphic.Series[0].ChartType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Line;
            tmpStrArr = null;
            x = 0;
            y = 0;

            sr.Close();
            ofd.Dispose();

        }


    }
```

I expect the output of 2 graphs, from 2 files, not 3 graphs from 2 files.

[image]

Comment: Can you show the result? Are the 3 graphs in the same chartarea? Could it be that the 2nd file holds too many data?

Comment: 2 Files are similar. 30 values for x, 30 values for y. Third graph, which I see - doesn't match with anothers. I can't understand where it takes this values. I don't know how to add pictures here(

Comment: There should be an icon to add an image when you are in editing mode, no?

Comment: I added pic. Thanks)

Comment: With chart an image often tells so much more than words or code..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are seeing are **not** as you suspect **three** 'graphs' but **two**!

But as the `ChartType` is `Line` and the last point of the 1st data portion ends at x=30 and the first of the 2nd file start at x=1 you see an extra line **connecting** these two datapoints.

`Line` is one of the few type that support x-values going forward and back.

You can change to `ChartType` `Point` to test. Or you can use a **2nd** `Series` for the 2nd file and the artifact will dissappear..

If you'd rather keep all points in the same series, **you can't prevent** the connecting line but **you can hide it** : You can start each set of datapoints with `Color.Transparent`, as the **line color is determined by the 2nd point**..:

```
int pt = chartGraphic.Series[0].Points.AddXY(x,y);
if (pt == 0) chartGraphic.Series[0].Points[pt].Color = Color.Transparent
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Now I understand. Where I can read more about adding series? I didn't understand very well how to use 2nd Series for another file

Comment: You can add a Series after the File dialog: `Series s = chartGraphic.Series.Add(someSeriesName)  { ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line };` . Use a nice name, maybe derived from the filename. The name will be displayed in he Legend, but you can set a different ` LegendText` if you want to.. If you want to use only the series you add , do delete the defautl series first: `chartGraphic.Series.Clear();`